# Unable to rollout release to alpha in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, publishing, alpha

I have uploaded my APK, and filled in data in every field which was required... but using Googles new MAnage releases tab, I am unable to press the final button to roll it out to alpha. Its not telling me I need to do anything else, but the button is inactive.

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are required to supply information in the sections marked with a grey checkmark (now a grey triangle with exclamation mark), in all required fields (marked with a blue asterisk). This includes, but isn't restricted to:

Pricing and Distribution:

- setting app availability to *all countries* (don't worry about this, read on),
- configuring presence of ads and being targeted *primarily* at children,
- confirming Android Content Guidelines compliance,
- acknowledging the app being subject to US export laws,
- configuring testing (you can have a closed alpha, hence countries doesn't matter at this stage)

Store listing:

- uploading feature graphics and even screenshots, yeah...

[image: A bit like this.]

Once that's done, you'll get *two* "Ready to publish" labels, at the top of the page, the right one being a link to the App Releases management section where you can complete your rollout.

[image: We're really ready now]

Yes, this is even more horrible UX than Google Play's previous light grey 'Why can't I publish?' help link on the top of the page. Make the best of it before the next iteration.=)

Comment: dam, it it mentioned on any place? I didn't saw that, and there is no message stating this fact. I am very grateful. Google always manages to to some of the worst user experiences

Comment: Glad it’s helped. Well, it was some 3 years ago so my memory of it is a bit hazy; I think that if I had found an end to end explanation somewhere, then I wouldn’t have bothered writing it up.=)